# Ucanaccess_net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference@ac6b76 folder

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

I am using UcanAccess(net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver) Driver to connect with MS Access Database ,I am able to interact with database but every time i start my server and db is loaded ,a file folder with name "Ucanaccess_net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference@194ac0b" is created on Desktop with the same size of DB(approx 250 MB).

Could any one provide solution?
Thanks

Comment: You should really ask this question in the [UCanAccess General Discussion Forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/general/) or the  [UCanAccess Help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/). At the very least look through the topics there. An answer may already be there.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using the `memory=false` connection option. In that case, the default location for the HSQLDB backing database is the same folder as the Access database file. You can use `mirrorFolder=<path>` to change the location where the backing database is stored.

Comment: yes i am using memory=false,but if i remove this,i get error:Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Okay, so your current JVM size is not large enough to accommodate the HSQLDB backing database using in-memory tables. `memory=false` tells HSQLDB to use on-disk tables, and the folder you are seeing is where those HSQLDB resources are stored. That is just how UCanAccess works.

Comment: @GordThompson Is there any way to stop this storing process? Because in my application the .mdb file needs to be accessed minimum 2 times everyday. So everyday >=1GB(each created folder size around 500MB) storage is gone from my 512GB file storage. And deleting folder every day is not a good process. So what can be done?